# GoogleDriveAPI C# Windows-Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a working C# programm which downloads and uploads files from Google Drive. The next step I wanted to do is to run my programm with a service periodically every 5 minutes. The service starts every 5 minutes, but my programm fails to authenticate to the GoogleDrive API (the credentials are null) and I don't know why.
I install and uninstall the service from my GUI program.
Note: I'm new to windows-services

```
public async Task Run()
    {

        UserCredential credential = null;
        System.IO.FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ServiceTest1\GoogleDrive\client_secrets.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
                Scopes, 
                "Cloud Manager", 
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("ServiceTest1")
            ).Result;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }


        await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "CloudManagerGD",
        });

        // For debug purpose only. 
        FileList fl = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
        About about = await service.About.Get().ExecuteAsync();

        await GetFiles(service, "trollol", fl);
        await PostFiles(service, "trollol", fl);

    }
```

Comment: If your credentials are null, this error is most likely because your access token has expired. You should be requesting for through a refresh token.

Comment: But another problem is that the Folder "ServiceTest1" in %AppData% is not even created/existing, that means the Service doesn't even get an access token.
Could the problem be that the service is started with the user 'System'?

Comment: the funny thing is my program works just fine on itself, but as soon as I implement it into a service I get these errors.

Comment: As you were questioning: yes, try to set different credentials to your service than 'System'. (i.e. in the properties "Log On" page, set your service to start with your user & password).

Comment: @cabbi I already try to fix this problem in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318838/windows-service-start-from-logged-in-user-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment43097929_27318838) but I only want to set the username and the user should confirm it with their password. I'm keeping you updated if this works.