# Windows Service start from logged in user c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I made a windows service (which is working), but it is running on the SYSTEM user and I want it to run on my current logged in user.

Here is my service installer class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
class CloudManagerServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public CloudManagerServiceInstaller()
    {
        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        var serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Username = Environment.MachineName + "\\carl";

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Z";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Z";

        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
    }

}
```

And there is my servicebase:

```
class CloudManagerServiceBase : ServiceBase
{
    public int i = 0;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private int m = 2;
    public CloudManagerServiceBase()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "ZSCloudManager";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(m * 60 * 1000); // every m minutes
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start(); // <- important



    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { do work }}
```

I install the service with the help of another progamm.
Can I write the service like that or do I have to follow these instructions -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx
If thats the case then can you please give me a code snippet, because i dont fully understand this.

Comment: A windows service does not require a user be logged in at all, there may be several users logged in. So what do you mean by you want to run the service as "the currenctly logged in user". Do you want to always run as a specific user or something else?

Comment: I think you want to change from a windows service to an application that runs when the user logs in.

Comment: Yes @Ben Robinson I want the service to always run as a specific user.

Comment: @AWinkle I actually want to integrate my application into my _timer_Elapsed event and run it when the user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up doing it manually and made it with the serivice preset from Visual Studio. I just added this to the preset (in the projectInstaller class):

```
public ProjectInstaller()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = ".\\" + Environment.UserName;
}
```

And set the Property Account from serviceProcessInstaller to "user". After that you can add your code in the Service class. It works fine for me.